# Find the joint pmf of X and Y. Prove that X and Y are not independent.

Tags: probability-distributions

A fair coin is tossed three times. Let X denote a random variable that takes the value 0 if the first toss is a head and the value 1 if the first toss is a tail. Let Y be a random variable that defines the total number of heads in the three tosses.
Find the joint pmf of X and Y. Prove that X and Y are not independent.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you having trouble?

Comment: im not sure how to solve this

Comment: Well, $\mathsf P(X=0, Y=1)=\tfrac 1{2^3}$ , being the probability that the first coin is a head and only one coin is a head.